# Very Long Dropdown Menus issue

Tags: jquery, css

I have used [Solution For Very Long Dropdown Menus](http://css-tricks.com/long-dropdowns-solution/) it's a great drop down menu but the problem is that I cannot set submenus (LEVEL TWO) width to be bigger than LEVEL ONE width

Any ideas?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rvfd5/2/)

[Fiddle with fix](http://jsfiddle.net/rvfd5/4/) Thank you dunli

[image: My menu screenshot]

CSS:

```
 /* 
        LEVEL ONE
    */
    ul.dropdown                         { position: absolute; width: 100%; }
    ul.dropdown li                      { float: right; position: relative; list-style-type:none; width: auto; text-align:center;  }
    ul.dropdown a:hover                 { color: #000;  }
    ul.dropdown li a                    { display: block; color: #222; position: relative; z-index: 2000;  }
    ul.dropdown li a:hover,
    ul.dropdown li a.hover              { background: #F3D673; position: relative; }
    .suca {
    width:100px;}

    /* 
        LEVEL TWO
    */
    ul.dropdown ul                      { display: none; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 80px !important; z-index: 1000; }
    ul.dropdown ul li                   { font-weight: normal; background: #f6f6f6; color: #000; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;  width:auto;}
    ul.dropdown ul li a                 { display: block; background: #eee !important; padding-right: 20px; width: 100px !important; } 
    ul.dropdown ul li a:hover           { display: block; background: #F3D673 !important; width: 100px !important; }
```

Comment: Can you make [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) for reference of your problem?

Comment: The problem maybe caused by `overflow:hidden;` in the `li` element. The trick you are using for long dropdown seems to be advisable for 1 level dropdown only. I think so.

Comment: Yep, you are right, the problem is caused by 'overflow:hidden', I deleted it from Jquery and added 'overflow:hidden' to 'ul.dropdown' in css and now the problem is that it is visible on scroll http://jsfiddle.net/rvfd5/3/

Comment: I have updated your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: I will post it as an answer. Mark it as answer to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have updated your `css` a little bit. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/rvfd5/4/)